# Microsoft SQL Server: Query to get single records when duplicate records exists for same ticket number

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to build a SQL query to return the latest updated ticket number in my table. Each time there is an update to the ticket, it will create another record in the table. ID field will be unique for each record.

I have tried using SELECT DISTINCT statement and MAX function in my sub-query, but was not able to get the desired output.

**Table**

```
ID     Ticket_Number  Priority  Assignee          Last_Updated_Date
21100        2          Low       Jerry          2018-9-13 15:10:01
21105        2         Medium     Chris          2018-9-15 23:10:08
21520        3          High      James, Alan    2018-9-14 08:10:11
22000        4          Low       Chris          2018-9-14 20:10:22
22150        4          High      Chris, Jerry   2018-9-16 11:00:00
23120        6          Low       Albert         2018-9-17 12:10:06
23220        7          High      Steve          2018-9-18 10:10:02
```

**Desired Output**

```
 ID     Ticket_Number  Priority  Assignee          Last_Updated_Date
21105        2         Medium     Chris          2018-9-15 23:10:08
21520        3          High      James, Alan    2018-9-14 08:10:11
22150        4          High      Chris, Jerry   2018-9-16 11:00:00
23120        6          Low       Albert         2018-9-17 12:10:06
23220        7          High      Steve          2018-9-18 10:10:02
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: If your RDBMS is MS SQL Server you could use analitical functions like LAG and LEAD or ROW_NUMBER.

Comment: This is SQL Server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the `ROW_NUMBER` window function:

```
SELECT ID, Ticket_Number, Priority, Assignee, Last_Updated_Date
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Ticket_Number ORDER BY Last_Updated_Date DESC) AS rn
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1;
```

or use co-related sub-query

```
select ID, Ticket_Number, Priority, Assignee, Last_Updated_Date from t t1
where t.Last_Updated_Date  in (select max(Last_Updated_Date from t t2 )
                               where t2.Ticket_Number  =t1.Ticket_Number  
                               group by t2.Ticket_Number)
```

Comment: My edit: Don't do `SELECT *` in the outer query, because that would include the row number, which maybe the OP doesn't want to see.

Comment: thanks @ZaynulAbadinTuhin The query deleted the duplicates. The issue I see now is some of the tickets that should be in the results are not showing up after I run the query. Any idea why?

Comment: @CWZY this query  is not for duplicate delete so if you use this for duplicate deletion then yes some ticket number will be lost (those are not duplicate)

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin thanks for the response. Any idea why the query might exclude some records?

Comment: @CWZY i already said that in my previous comment .. this query will always pick latest  Last_Updated_Date entry of each ticket number ,as a result those ticket number has only one entry also fall that territory and lost from records set if you delete by using this but if you want delete then you have to use rn<>1 or rn>1 in where condition

Comment: @CWZY if any ones answer help please accept his answer

Answer (score 0):

try using following query :

```
select a.* from yourtable a
inner join 
(select distinct Ticket_Number,max(Last_Updated_Date) as Last_Updated_Date from yourtable 
group by Ticket_Number) b
on a.Ticket_Number = b.Ticket_Number and a.Last_Updated_Date = b.Last_Updated_Date
```

Comment: You don't need distinct with group by

Comment: @paparazzo and maheshparab thanks for the reply. I tried using this query, but now some of the tickets are not showing up in the output query.

Answer (score -1):

```
WITH cte AS 
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Last_Updated_Date DESC) rn,* FROM t)

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM cte WHERE rn=1 ORDER BY ID
```

I think It would work if your RDBMS is Microsoft SQL Server.